# How to cache data on Android using Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

Let's say I've 3 screens,

1. `HomeScreen`, which contains list of users
2. `UserProfileScreen`, which contains user details and their posts
3. `PostDetailScreen`, which contains details about post

```kotlin
@Composable
fun HomeScreen() {
    LazyColumn {
        // Show user profiles
    }
}
```

```kotlin
@Composable
fun UserProfileScreen(
    userId: Long,
    userProfileViewModel: UserProfileViewModel
) {
    LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
        userProfileViewModel.getProfileAndPosts(userId)
    }
    
    UserProfileView()
    LazyColumn {
        // Show posts
    }
}
```

```kotlin
@Composable
fun PostDetailScreen(
    postId: Long,
    postViewModel: PostViewModel
) {
    LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
        postViewModel.getPost(postId)
    }

    PostView()
}
```

When I move from `HomeScreen` to `UserProfileScreen`, I use `LaunchedEffect(Unit) {}` to fetch user profile and posts from network. And if I click on any post, it will navigate to `PostDetailScreen` and display post details.

Now, If I come back to `UserProfileScreen` (via backpress), it will re-fetch the user data because `getProfileAndPosts()` is a function and accept `userId` so (I guess) can't be cached to `viewModelScope` (If it were variable without any parameter, we can cache it)

How do I avoid that? Instagram seems to does exactly that. It does not re-fetch data. Though, they're on XML view, but it should not make any difference.

Comment: Using a shared ViewModel would be a good idea.

Comment: ViewModel is already mentioned in post, kindly have a re-look

Comment: I suggested a common ViewModel for all three screens.

Comment: That's not a good option for me. I'm using separate `ViewModel` to separate the logic.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your problem correctly

You must use ViewModel.
And define a data class with this name:

```
data class UserProfileState(
val wereThePostsReceived : Boolean = false,
val posts : List<Post> = emptyList()
)
```

And change its value to true after successfully receiving the posts in ViewModel.

```
fun getProfileAndPosts(userId : String) {
  viewModelScope.launch {
    val result = getPostsUseCase(userId)
      when(result) {
        is Succuss -> {
          state = state.copy(
             wereThePostsReceived = true,
            posts = // your interactor , usecase result
          )
        is Failed -> {
     }
  }
}
```

Then use it in the Compose layout as follows:

```
  LaunchedEffect(wereThePostsReceived) {
  if(wereThePostsReceived == false){
        postViewModel.getProfileAndPosts(postId)
   }
  }
```

Comment: What is the use of this? I'm getting `getProfileAndPosts` and then navigate to `PostDetailScreen`, so `UserProfileScreen` and `UserProfileViewModel` will be cleared. Now, when i return via backpress, it will be re-initialised and need to fetch data again.